# не работает animate

Tags: jquery, animate

```
не работает animate, что я делаю неправильно???

$('.container').mousemove(function(e){
var X = e.pageX; // положения по оси X
var Y = e.pageY; // положения по оси Y
console.log("X: " + X + " Y: " + Y); // вывод результата в консоль
 if (X>9) {
 $(".ball").animate({
top: X
 },100);
}
else{

};
});
```

Comment: мб  position: absolute; не хватает? в след раз выкладывай больше кода)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так как Вы не включили в вопрос разметку и стили, сказать, что Вы делаете неправильно, затруднительно. Вот что, я думаю, Вы хотели сделать:

```js
$('.container').mousemove(function(e) {
  var X = e.pageX; // положения по оси X
  var Y = e.pageY; // положения по оси Y
  //console.log("X: " + X + " Y: " + Y); // вывод результата в консоль
  if (X > 9) {
    $(".ball").animate({
      left: X + "px",
      top: Y + "px"
    }, 50);
  } else {

  };
});
```

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: lightgray;
  width:100%;
  height:180px;
}
.ball {
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
CONTAINER
<div class="ball">BALL</div>
</div>
```

Comment: у меня не работало из-за этого:      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>;   после го добавления все заработало. Спасибо!!!     А до этого просто добавлял <script type="text/javascript" src="jQuery.js"></script>    и внутри этого файла был jQuery.   А какая разница между ними???